# Bayes Theorem Breast Cancer

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

This is a famous introductory problem to Bayes theorem, but I'm having trouble with my answer and I need someone to tell me what I am doing wrong. The problem goes:

> $10$ out of $1000$ women aged $40$ and over participating in routine screenings have breast cancer. $8$ out of $10$ women with breast cancer will get a positive mammography. $95$ out of $990$ women without breast cancer will get a positive mammography.

- a) What is  the probability of a false positive?
- b) What is the probability of a false negative?

Now usually when approached with a Baye's theory problem, I make a tree. Like:

- Breast Cancer $(\frac{10}{1000})$ -> Positive $(\frac{8}{10})$ / Negative $(\frac{2}{10})$
- Not Breast Cancer $(\frac{990}{1000})$ -> Positive $(\frac{95}{990})$ / Negative $(\frac{895}{990})$

(Sorry ahead of time for the formatting. I wasn't sure how to create a tree diagram here, but I think you get the point. Leave me a comment if anything is unclear)

So starting with a) (and for right now since b) is pretty close to a) we can essentially focus on that) the probability we are looking for is $P(CancerFree \mid PositiveTest)$. Although we can shortcut it by doing 1 - $\frac{895}{990}$ I believe to get the answer, for the sake of my understanding I want to do it the long way. Thus, we implement Baye's Rule:
$$ = \frac{P(PositiveTest \mid CancerFree) * P(CancerFree)}{P(PositiveTest)}$$
$$ = \frac{(\frac{2}{10})(\frac{990}{1000})}{(\frac{990}{1000})(\frac{95}{990})+(\frac{10}{1000})(\frac{8}{10})}$$

However, mathematically this doesn't come out right. Would someone be able to help me understand? Thanks so much in advance for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Since you've got an actual population here, using Bayes' theorem is overkill. For instance, to get a true positive, you need to be one of the 8 women---out of 8+95=103 women who tested positive---who actually have breast cancer. Hence a false positive should have a probability of $95/103$.

Comment: Similar Q&A [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1755841/probability-and-bayes-theorem/1755865#1755865)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not so much a fan of probability trees.  I like tables.  In any case, always define your events precisely.  Here I will use $$T = \text{A randomly selected person tests positive,} \\ C = \text{A randomly selected person has breast cancer.}$$  Furthermore, $\bar T$ and $\bar C$ represent the complementary events of testing negative and not having cancer, respectively.  Then for the following table structure
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} & C & \bar C & \\ \hline
T & n_{11} = T \cap C & n_{12}  = T \cap \bar C & n_{1*} = n_{11} + n_{12} \\ \hline
\bar T & n_{21} = \bar T \cap C & n_{22} = \bar T \cap \bar C & n_{2*} = n_{21} + n_{22} \\ \hline
& n_{*1} = n_{11} + n_{21} & n_{*2} = n_{12} + n_{22} & n_{**}\end{array}$$
we are given the following frequencies:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} & C & \bar C & \\ \hline
T & 8 & 95 & ?\\ \hline
\bar T & ? & ? & ? \\ \hline
& 10 & 990 & 1000\end{array}$$  Filling in the blanks is trivial:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} & C & \bar C & \\ \hline
T & 8 & 95 & 103\\ \hline
\bar T & 2 & 895 & 897 \\ \hline
& 10 & 990 & 1000\end{array}$$ 
Now the probability of a false positive is simply $$\Pr[T \mid \bar C] = \frac{\Pr[T \cap \bar C]}{\Pr[\bar C]} = \frac{n_{12}}{n_{*2}} = \frac{95}{990}.$$  Indeed, this could be immediately stated from the question; no computation was needed.  The probability of a false negative is $$\Pr[\bar T \mid C] = \frac{\Pr[\bar T \cap C]}{\Pr[C]} = \frac{n_{21}}{n_{*1}} = \frac{2}{10},$$ only slightly less trivial than the previous question.  So we can see there's no real need to rigorously do any Bayesian calculations--the questions ask for information that is readily found from the given conditions.

Be advised that the definition of false positive and false negative are as follows:

> **false positive:**  A test result is positive when the true condition is negative.
>
> **false negative:**  A test result is negative when the true condition is positive.

Do not confuse this with false discovery and false omission:  false positive and false negative have to do with the chance of the test giving a result that is contradictory to the true condition, rather than the condition being actually present (absent) when the test is positive (negative).

If the question had asked, "what is the positive predictive value (PPV) of the test; i.e., what is the chance that someone who tests positive actually has breast cancer," then this would be $$\Pr[C \mid T] = \frac{\Pr[T \cap C]}{\Pr[T]} = \frac{8}{103}.$$  This is a horrible rate; it means that less than $8\%$ of women with a positive mammogram actually have breast cancer; thus mammography should not be used as a diagnostic tool.

What is the negative predictive value (NPV) of the test; i.e., if a woman tests negative, what is the probability she in fact does not have breast cancer?  This is $$\Pr[\bar C \mid \bar T] = \frac{\Pr[\bar T \cap \bar C]}{\Pr[\bar T]} = \frac{895}{897},$$ which is very high:  it means a woman testing negative can be fairly assured that she does not have breast cancer.  So, mammography's utility, according to the problem, seems to be in providing reassurance for those who test negative.

Comment: So when both @AlgorithmsX and Semiclassical found the probability to be 95/103, what probability did they find in regard to false positives?

Comment: @BillyThorton We have $\Pr[\bar C \mid T] = 95/103$ and $\Pr[C \mid \bar T] = 2/897$.  These are called the false discovery rate and false omission rate, respectively.  See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity for details.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I don't think I quite understand the difference. Would you be able to provide a better explanation?

Comment: @BillyThorton A false positive occurs when someone who we know is actually negative for a condition, erroneously tests positive.  A false discovery occurs when someone who we know to test positive, in fact does not have the condition.  When calculating the incidence (proportion), both of these have the same numerator, but the denominator is different:  the false positives are counted among those we know to not have the condition.  The false discoveries are counted among those we know to have tested positive.  The first is $\Pr[T \mid \bar C]$; the second is $\Pr[\bar C \mid T]$.

Answer (score 1):

$P(PositiveTest|CancerFree)=\frac{95}{990}$. Also, your shortcut does not work because it fails to take into account the positive results for those that do have cancer. The actual answer is $\frac{95}{95+8}=\frac{95}{103}$.

The false negative is $\frac{10-8}{990-95+10-8}=\frac2{897}$

Comment: Is everything else right? And why not the $\frac{2}{10}$ since that is the value you are looking for?